# Duplicate questions which are more viewed than the referenced one

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Since I've been on Stack Overflow, I have noticed something:

There are a lot of questions marked as duplicate but are read more than the original question.

Here is an example:

[The question marked as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234241/how-are-echo-and-print-different-in-php) → 127k views

[The original one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094118/reference-comparing-phps-print-and-echo) → 10k views

Most of the time these are old questions.

I think we should find a system, like a kind of merge of the two questions, to get the most read one as the reference.

We could continue to exchange on those questions and points on the most read one.

Comment: Why is this a problem? The duplicate links to the master. (Merges are an option, they're just moderator-only.)

Comment: There is one more click to do to got the referenced question. On our world, it's a lot...

I'm pretty sure most of the people don't even go to the referenced question. And took the marked as duplicate one as the reference, they miss informations and datas which could be useful..

Comment: There is no world in which one click is a lot. If people don't bother to go to the referenced question, they don't want to know very badly. Lots of people don't bother to read any of the answers except the first. Merging won't solve that problem, either.

Comment: The newer question is a community wiki and was designed to be the dupe target for this topic. So the current situation is how it's supposed to be. It doesn't matter which one has more views.

Answer (score -9):

I agree with this.  I find few things more frustrating than to google a question, and the top result being a post asking the question, just to have the answer be "please google the answer"

Finding questions closed as duplicates as top results is equally frustrating.  I strongly believe that we should strive to have the top SO google result be an answer, and not the community criticizing a poster

Comment: If you find an answer that says that, flag it as not an answer (or flag a comment as not constructive).  If you're not logged in, the site automatically redirects to the target (not sure what the exact rules are).

Comment: Not clear how "community criticizing a poster" relates to "duplicate" asked in the question...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov seeing "marked as duplicate" is a negative thing

Comment: @Andrey I see... Which is unfortunate since it is common misconception and absolutely not the goal of duplicates. You may want to ask separate question on META about why you believe that duplicates are negative and what can be done about it.